# Got an unexpected keyword argument, genuinely stumped

Tags: python, machine-learning, syntax, parameter-passing, argument-unpacking

I've got the following code. I'll include only the problematic bits:

```
class C:
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    def fit(...):
        ...
        c = self.learner(**self.kwargs)
```

I'm attempting to use this with the following class:

```
class learner:
    def __init__(self, X):
        self.X = X
```

```
kwargs={'X': X}
inst = C(kwargs=kwargs)
inst.fit(...)
```

Which is yielding the error, at the line `inst.fit(...)`. The error is:  `learner.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'kwargs'`. How do I fix my instantiation? It seems as though the dictionary is not being unpacked, despite employing `**`. Help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Note that your issue would appear more clearly if you remove all unnecessary code. Do we need much more than the `def ...` line and the line where you call it ?

Comment: Please see the duplicate question on how to properly use kwargs.

Answer (score 0):

By destructuring your `kwargs` in the constructor of `Boost` what you are actually storing in `self.kwargs` is a dictionary that looks like this:

```py
{'kwargs': {'X': x_train, 'y': y_train, 'stride': 12, 's_stride': 17 }
```

Passing this to the `wk_learner` constructor using `**self.kwargs` means python tries to look for a keyword argument called `kwargs` which doesn't exist, hence the error message.

You can fix the problem by not destructuring in the `Boost` constructor (and maybe also renaming the parameter to avoid confusion):

```
def __init__(self, base_learner, base_learner_kwargs):
    self.base_learner = base_learner
    self.base_learner_kwargs = base_learner_kwargs

def fit(self, X: np.ndarray, y: np.ndarray):
    ...
    clf = self.base_learner(**self.base_learner_kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you explicitly define a keyword argument `kwargs` in your function call

```py
inst = Boost(base_learner=wk_learner, kwargs=kwargs)
```

which your `wk_learner` class does not know how to use.

What I assume you want to do is to just just pass the contents of kwargs via

```py
inst = Boost(base_learner=wk_learner, **kwargs)
```

Note that `args` and `kwargs` are not defined names for a list of arguments and a dictionary of keyword arguments. They are just established default names. You can use any variable name instead.